# Coordinate Reference System not Recognized in gvNIX

Tags: gvnix

In reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739056/using-gvnix-to-create-map-based-application/34748212#34748212) I am trying to create a map based web application using gvNIX to hold location data on health faciilities. Am following [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739056/using-gvnix-to-create-map-based-application/34748212#34748212) as a guide. When issuing the command:

```
web mvc geo controller --class ~.web.MapViewerController --preferredMapping Tanzania --projection EPSG4210
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert 'EPSG4210' to type ProjectionCRSTypes for option 'projection'
No enum constant org.gvnix.addon.geo.addon.ProjectionCRSTypes.EPSG4210
```

Am new to GIS and am assuming that EPSG4210 is the correct Coordinate Referencing System for Tanzania? How may I overcome this error?

Kind regards,
T

Answer (score 0):

This projection is not included on gvNIX, so it can't handle it by default.

To use this projection you must follow this steps:

1. Create the view using a register projection (4326 by example)
2. Modify *show.jspx* to use your projection (EPSG4210)
3. Register this projection in [proj4leaflet-custom-proj.js file](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-geo-app/src/main/webapp/scripts/leaflet/proj4leaflet-custom-proj.js) (there you can find an example which defines EPSG:25830) (see [leaflet plugin project](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet))

   Good luck!